# Bash: How to translate modification time of a file to epoch?

Tags: bash, shell, date

I've got a task at work... to automate all products release procedures.

One of the steps is to stop the online process of the company, To do that, I need to log into the java dashboard which was coded in-house, stop a specific java task, `tail -f` the log and when no new data is written - it means the system is ready to start the release procedure.

I intend to use the `stat` command to find the last modification date and time of the log file, but in order to make it easier for me to work with that value, I'd like to translate it to Epoch time, how is it done?

I know how to do the opposite translation.. that is `date -d@1415800764` for example.

Comment: If your `date` supports the `-r` flag, use it instead of `stat`: `date -r file +%s` will output the modification time of the file `file` in Epoch time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
date --date="Wed Nov 12 14:59:24 CET 2014" +%s
```

Output will be:

```
# 1415800764
```

Works for many formats, e.g.

```
 date --date="12-NOV-14" +%s
```

Comment: that's the way I used it: `date --date "$date $time" +%s`

Answer (score 4):

If you are already using `stat` then just have it give you the output you want. Use the `%Y` format.

So instead of (or whatever)

```
$ stat c | grep ^Modify
Modify: 2014-11-12 07:17:29.000000000 -0500
```

Use

```
$ stat -c %Y c
1415794649
```

Comment: +1, but check the documentation for your version of `stat` to use the correct options. BSD `stat` uses `-f` instead of `-c`.