# How to use get Last modified time from file stored in Variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

My goal is to get the last modified time from a file stored in a variable. EPOCH would be preferred, but as of now I can't get the date using "date -r" at the very least.

*As you can see below I store the file I want in the variable "$oldestfile"
Then I try to execute "date -r" against it to get the last modified time but it errors out. PLEASE HELP!!*

```
jssteele89@JAREDSTEELEB41F:~$ oldestfile=`ls -Ulta f41895.archivetosmarsh.com/emailarchive*/Maildir | grep .duplicated999 | tail -n 1`
jssteele89@JAREDSTEELEB41F:~$ echo $oldestfile
drwxr-xr-x 1 jssteele89 jssteele89 4096 Jun 30 11:10 .duplicated999
jssteele89@JAREDSTEELEB41F:~$ date -r $oldestfile
date: extra operand ‘jssteele89’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
jssteele89@JAREDSTEELEB41F:~$
```

Comment: Look at all the stuff that's in `$oldestfile`. BTW: Don't just throw random tags at a question, study their description first.

Comment: Your primary problem is -- as in your other question -- you're using `ls -l`, so the output isn't a *filename*, it's a human-readable description of the metadata including permissions, owner, group, and file size. You can't just use that as an argument to `date -r` and expect it to work; for `date -r` you need **just the filename**.

Comment: @larsks is there a way to extract the filename from the variable? then I could use that against "date -r"?

Comment: I would solve this problem by using `awk` command.
So $oldestfile would looks like next:
```oldestfile=$(ls -Ulta f41895.archivetosmarsh.com/emailarchive*/Maildir | grep .duplicated999 | awk '{print $NF}' | tail -n 1)```
So once you will run ```date -r $oldestfile``` you will receive the last modified date of that file

Comment: You don't need the `-l` in your `ls` command. Using `ls -Uta` instead of `ls -Ulta` would give you just filenames. There are still issues involved in parsing the output of `ls`, but that may be fine for what you're doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash: How to translate modification time of a file to epoch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888867/bash-how-to-translate-modification-time-of-a-file-to-epoch)

Comment: Also see [BashFAQ/003 (How can I sort or compare files based on some metadata attribute (newest / oldest modification time, size, etc)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003).

Answer (score 2):

The `stat` command is what you're after:

```bash
mtime=$(stat -c '%Y' filename)
```

`stat` options vary by OS, so make sure to read the man page.

---

`find` is also helpful

```bash
find /path -name '*.duplicated999*' -printf '%T@\t%p\n'
```